# My Rock Paper Scissors game won't display ties

Tags: java

I've written this rock paper scissors code in BlueJ and so far everything's working great...except one thing. The game won't tell me when I have tied with the computer. It will tell me what the computer has used and it will tell me if I have won or lost. If I have tied, however, it will simply tell me what the computer has used and ignore the tie. The code is below.
~~~

```
/**
*A simple game of Rock Paper Scissors.
*
*@author Erik Ingvoldsen
*@version 1.0
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Rock
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String playAgain = "4";    
do
    {
    String personPlay;
    String computerPlay = "";
    int computerInt;
    String response;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();
    System.out.println("   ");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Rock, 2 for Scissors, 3 for Paper, and 4 to quit.");
    System.out.println();
    computerInt = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
    if (computerInt == 1)
       computerPlay = "Rock";
    else if (computerInt == 2)
       computerPlay = "Scissors";
    else if (computerInt == 3)
       computerPlay = "Paper";
    //1=Rock 2=Scissors 3=Paper
    {System.out.println("Rock Paper Scissors: ");
    {personPlay = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Computer chooses: " + computerPlay);
    if (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)){ 
       System.out.println("It's a tie!");}
    else if (personPlay.equals("1")){
       if (computerPlay.equals("Paper"))
          System.out.println("Paper beats rock. Loser.");
    else if (computerPlay.equals("Scissors"))
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors. Winner.");}
    else if(personPlay.equals("2")){
       if (computerPlay.equals("Paper"))
          System.out.println("Scissors beats paper. Winner");
    else if (computerPlay.equals("Rock"))
            System.out.println("Rock beats scissors. Loser.");}
   else if (personPlay.equals("3")) {
       if (computerPlay.equals("Rock"))
          System.out.println("Paper beats rock. Winner.");
   else if (computerPlay.equals("Scissors"))
            System.out.println("Scissors beats paper. Loser.");}
   else
System.out.println("Not a valid key. Cheaters never win.");}
System.out.println("Press 4 to quit or any other key to continue.");
Scanner End = new Scanner(System.in);
String quit=End.nextLine();
if(quit.equals("4"))
{
System.exit(0);}
}
}while(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are attempting to compare `"1"` to `"Paper"` and expecting `true`.

Either make both comparisons `true`, i.e. comparing the user input to `"1"` and the computer to `"Paper"`, or translate `"1"` to `"Paper"` (and the other two values correspondingly) and the compare the responses directly.

Answer (score 0):

personPlay can be 1, 2 or 3.
computerPlay can be Paper, Rock or Scissors.

Therefore the line `f (personPlay.equals(computerPlay)){` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are trying to compare a number to a String with this line

```
personPlay.equals(computerPlay)
```

Here `personPlay` is the number entered by the person (read in as a String) and `computerPlay` is the String that you have set based on the number the computer got i.e. `computerInt`.

Easy fix is to change the above comparison to check the String value of `computerInt`

```
personPlay.equals(String.valueOf(computerInt))
```

So the numbers are compared (as Strings)